# Android Device Chooser -- device not showing up

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, device, adb

I'm using Eclipse + ADT, and my physical device (listed below) is unlisted on Android Device Chooser. I have updated Eclipse and all of the Android packages. My phone is running Android OS 1.6, which corresponds to the target version listed in the Eclipse Project.

Also, the reason I decided to try testing on a real device is because the emulator doesn't seem to be working right anymore when I run my project. The emulator launches, but the program never does. Any ideas?

(using windows 7/t-mobile mytouch 3g)

Comment: I Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/why-is-eclipses-android-device-chooser-not-showing-my-android-device/31587496#31587496) will help everyone facing the same issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this was because the option for USB debugging wasn't checked on the device

Comment: Settings --> Applications -->Developer

Comment: To enable USB debugging is different between Android versions now. See my answer here that's updated:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256884/android-device-chooser-device-not-showing-up/14042812#14042812

Comment: I had the same problem, my divice was not listed in adv. but i realised that my problem was pluging the usb cable to wrong PC! i use two PCs and i mixed up the USB sockets:) Always think about all the possible causes

Comment: Just follow the steps from Android Developer site http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Answer (score 151):

First, make sure that the Android ADB can "talk to" your device.

- Open a Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe)/Mac Terminal.
- Go to the folder (via `cd`) where ADB.exe is in, e.g, C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools.
- Type `adb devices`

If your device is listed (serial number is displayed), go to the second check. Otherwise, this means ADB currently can't talk to your device. There're many reasons which can cause the problem, try:

- In your device, turn on "USB Debugging Mode" in Settings -> Application -> Development.
- In your device, turn on "Allow installation of non-market Applications" in Settings -> Application -> Development.
- Restart your Windows/Mac.
- Restart the Android device.
- In Windows/Mac, reinstall device drivers.

Second, make sure you set the "Deployment target selection mode" to manual:

- In Eclipse Package Explorer view, right click your Project, select Run As -> Run Configurations...
- In Run Configurations dialog, under Android Application. If your app doesn't exist, double click Android Application to create a new configuration, give it a suitable name (e.g. your app). Make sure this configuration is selected.
- On the right area, for Android tab, make sure your project displayed under Project; for Target tab, select "Always prompt to select device" or "manual".
- Click "Apply" and close the Run Configurations dialog.
  The next time when you Run your app, you should see your list of devices.

Your device still can't display? Ok. Third, make sure your "Project Build Target" Android version is supported in your Device.

- Check your device's Android version. In your device, select Settings->About Device.
- Check Android version of your project. Right click your project->Properties->Android->ProjectBuildTarget.
- Make sure that it's not newer than your device's version.

Comment: Thank you, it was a driver problem with my HTC.  Downloading and installing the latest Windows driver solved my problem.

Comment: To enable USB debugging is different between Android versions now.  See my answer here that's updated:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256884/android-device-chooser-device-not-showing-up/14042812#14042812

Comment: For Nexus 4, I installed the drivers according to the instructions on this site: http://androidsecurity.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/install-google-nexus-4-adb-usb-drivers-on-windows-android-studio

Comment: After above steps following error I see
[Xtouck] adb is running normally.
[Xtouck] Performing com.example.xtouck.MainActivity activity launch
[Xtouck] Automatic Target Mode: using device '0123456543ABCDEFG'
[Xtouck] Uploading Xtouck.apk onto device '0123456543ABCDEFG'
[Xtouck] Installing Xtouck.apk...
An internal error occurred during: "Launching Xtouck".
com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.installRemotePackage(Ljava/lang/String;Z[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: The Project Build Target was my problem.

Comment: Another thing to try if you device is not showing up is to ensure that you have enabled a USB computer connection: `Settings` > `Storage` > `USB Computer Connection`

Comment: Just follow the steps from Android Developer site http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: Thanks, for me it's the option "launch on all active devices"

Answer (score 22):

Also remember to set the 'Deployment target selection mode' to manual (Debug configurations -> target tab)

Answer (score 21):

After following some of the steps in other answers here, as well as what is found here: [ADB Driver for HTC Incredible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731871/adb-driver-for-htc-incredible), I had to issue two commands before my phone would show up.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Finally, after those two commands would my device show up when I ran

```
adb devices
```

From time to time, the ADB process may get *stuck* (technical term there).  When that happens, the above commands will not work.  I have found that killing the ADB process (look in for `adb.exe` in the Processes tab in Task Manager on Windows, or kill the PID for adb under linux), and then use

```
adb start-server
```

generally fixes that problem.

Answer (score 8):

This [note](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) from the Android Developer site is what worked for me:

> Enable USB debugging on your device. On most devices running Android
>   3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings > Applications > Development. On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer
>   options. Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden
>   by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap
>   Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find
>   Developer options.

Comment: Be sure to tap seven times on the "Build number" because anything else wouldn't be intuitive.

Comment: I have unlocked developer settings and got USB debugging on on my Galaxy Nexus but it does not get recognized by Eclipse.

Comment: Make sure it is in "Media Device" mode and not "Camera" mode when plugged in.

Comment: I had to hit "Run" (which showed no devices), then on the device toggle USB debug off and then on. My device then showed up in the device list. This has to be done every time I run :(

Answer (score 4):

Using the Android SDK Manager may or may not actually install the Google USB Driver.

Following the steps here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver allowed Eclipse to display the device.

Answer (score 3):

If you select Android Application in the Debug As dialog, you should be able to attach the debugger to the device directly. Make sure you run adb devices on your shell and see your device listed. If not, you will need to re-install the driver for the device. You can uninstall the drivers you have using USBdeview and then download and re-install the drivers until you see the serial number for the device listed when you run adb devices. - Arunabh Das

Answer (score 3):

None of the other answers worked for me. For me the device registered with eclipse after I rebooted the phone. Process for that is going to vary by phone model.

Comment: I got the two devices (Android v. 2.3.4 = API 10, v. 4.0.3 = API 15) to register only after rebooting both the phones and my Mac. OS 10.8.2, Android tools: 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525.

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

Windows 7

To install the Android USB driver on Windows 7 for the first time:

Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
Select Devices in the left pane.
Locate and expand Other device in the right pane.
Right-click the device name (such as Nexus S) and select Update Driver Software. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
Select Browse my computer for driver software and click Next.
Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
Click Next to install the driver.

Comment: For people still having problems after following this step (yellow warning sign in Device Manager on driver), uninstall the driver, then scan for driver changes. I tried updating driver but it wasn't picking up the file correctly. Uninstalling/reinstalling did the trick :-)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem...and my issue was related to using too high of an sdk....

I changed:

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/
```

to

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"
```

and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

I'm very late here, but if it helps someone... be sure you don´t have a conflict with your USB mode when attaching the cable. I pick "Only charge" (sorry if it's not exact, I have an Spanish terminal) but sometimes it changes to share net and the device dissapears from the list when running an app.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the android device not showing in "device chooser" so I try my best but no avail, at least I found that ADB drivers should update, for this I did following steps
 1. download driver from"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1161769"
 2. Device Manager->> right click on ADB ->> update driver ->>browse path of downloaded drivers then OK
 update successful.
 and I found my android device in "Device Chooser"
 try and getting relax

Answer (score 2):

If you have a samsung device you need to install a special driver for development:

http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

Answer (score 1):

Okay... so I could never get my PENDO pad to show up.. until I encountered this..

> process android.process.acore has stopped..

Yeah.. nothing to do with this issue right?  Ah ah but it lead me to MOBILEGO.  It's a desk application that lets you admin your device.. Guess how.. by connecting via USB.  Yep and it does.. It installed everything on my windows box, and now Eclipse has no problem seeing my PENDO.

Comment: When I googled to work out why my pendo pad wasn't working with eclipse, it led me to this answer. I tried mobilego and it didn't help me. What solved it for me was this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7136003/148241

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative: on modern Apple iMac's, the USB port closest to the outside edge of the machine never works with ADB, whereas all others work fine. I've seen this on two different iMacs, possibly those are USB 1.0 ports (or something equally stupid) - or it's a general manufacturing defect.

Plugging USB cables (new, old, high quality or cheap) into all other USB ports works fine, but plugging into that one fails ADB

NB: plugging into that port *works* for file-transfer, etc - it's only ADB that breaks.

Answer (score 1):

In galaxy note 3 you need to enable the developer option. Access the "About Device" and click on the Build number multiple time until a message appear which telling you that the developer option has been enabled. Go back to general and there your go..the developer option has been enabled and select USB debugging option. This is for Galaxy note 3 N9005 Andriod 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with an old ZTE phone, I was ignoring the autorun.exe that kept popping up when I plugged in the phone.  I finally ran the autorun software it installed ZTE drivers and the phone started showing up in adb devices.

Answer (score 1):

The device was not showing up because of the following line in android manifest file---

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>
```

I changed it to---

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

Now it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Disable debugging mode and developer options in your phone.

Start Android device monitor.

Now enable developer options and debugging mode in your phone.

You should be able to see your device listed after this in android device monitor. There after you should be able to see it under Android device chooser.

Answer (score 0):

My device had disappeared from the adb devices list after connecting it to adb on another laptop.

I selected "Charge only" on the phone and then re-enabled USB debugging.

That resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a MAC and for some reason when I connected my device via USB there was a weird mount called USB-Drivers which when I UNmounted from Finder, the Androide Device Chooser instantly recognized my device.

Answer (score 0):

Use USBDeview, from here, http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html

Run as administrator.

Disconnect your phone.

Delete all the drivers associated with your phone. Some will say Android as well as the name and model of the phone.

Plug your phone back in so that Windows re-installs the drivers.

This worked for me, when the other solutions didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have an HTC G2 with Win 8 and it took me hours to get Eclipse to recognize the device. I followed all of the advice above to no avail when I found this on http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1964372:

> Now click with the right mouse button on Computer, click Manage. Go to
>   Device Manager. Right click Acer A700, click update driver software.
>   Choose "Browe my computer for driver software". Choose "Let me pick
>   from a list". Click all devices or/and Have disk.. Go to C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\ and click
>   the file under the 2 folders (android_winusb.inf) Click on the first
>   one and install.

Substitute "Android Phone" under "Other devices" for "Acer A700" and use the android_winusb file under adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver. Click "OK" when you get the scary prompt about Windows becoming unstable and presto!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved this way: my phone is a SonyEricsson Xperia X8 and wasn't recognized by windows 7 (but it was by Ubuntu). Hence I figured out it was a driver problem.

0) Pluged in my smartphone
1) Right clicked on Computer->Manage->Device Manager
2) There was a yellow exclamation mark on one item named something like "SEMC HUSB"... Double clicked on that item (that was actually related to the smarphone) and updated the drivers (previously downloaded from this page http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/sony-ericsson-x8-drivers/ and now everything works). I guess that you can find your proper dirvers via google if you have a different phone.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

And , if your device is a Sony Ericsson Xperia X8 with the original ROM (2.1) or similar, then use:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml   file

Answer (score 0):

I had to goto "Settings->Developer options->USB debugging".  Make sure USB debugging is turned on.

*Samsung Galaxy S II Skyrocket*

*Android 4.1.2*

*Mac 10.8.5*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Sony Experia Z, that is because I'm running on windows 8 and apparently I need to download a driver for it.

As mentioned by stkhou, I check my Device manager and saw the eclamation mark.
Which it was the model of my phone, to double check so I remove the usb and it dissapeard.
So I plug it in again and the icon appears again.

So it's pretty sure the driver issue, so I have download it and install.
After installation, run the android device chooser on eclipse again and it works for me.

I hope same for you.

Here below I saved the links that might intrests someone who has sony issue. ;)

Here are the list of available driver for sony devices:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/

Sony SDK

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is to check Android SDK Manager and install Google USB Driver in Extras folder if you have not installed it.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the options work, I change the port and then enable USB debugging and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem seeing my android device, so when adb reported that none were present, I cycled power on my USB hub and voilà, it came back in adb and in eclipse DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my checklist when my device is not shown:

1. Make sure "USB debugging is turned in setting>Developer options.
2. Check status bar on your device. It tells you if your phone is connected as Media Device (MTP) or Send images (PTP). My device is only listed when PTP is selected.
3. Turn of windows firewall.
4. Turn of any proxy programs ran on whole windows ports.
5. And final solution to stop adb.exe from windows task manager and wait some seconds to restart automatically.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to do is swap cables.  I was using one that was only capable of charging!

Answer (score -1):

For **Micromax** devices :

You need to download third party PC-Suite like **Moborobo** or **Mobogenie** because Micormax don't have official PC-Suite & after installaion (without restarting) your mobile will be detected. :)