# Android Device not showing up in device chooser

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Device Chooser — device not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256884/android-device-chooser-device-not-showing-up)

Does anybody have an idea what I may be doing wrong. I have installed the usb drivers and have my device running in debugging mode but when I run my basic hello world application through eclipse my device wont show up in the device chooser. I have also tried re installing the sdk and all the drivers and still no luck. Thanks to anybody that can help me out

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem (on Linux). Running 'adb start-server' manually as root solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

my nexus one does this to me sometimes.  I have to toggle debug mode on the phone off/on and sometimes I even have to reboot the phone to fix it.  Usually when this happens I type

```
adb devices
```

My phone will actually show up in the list but say 'offline'

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes up often. Restarting the ADB server solves this problem most of the times.

Comment: How does one restart the ADB server?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Although it was working fine for a long time it suddenly sopped working. I tried to reinstall driver, reboot phone, pc, restart adb server etc but nothing worked. At the end I was able to fix it by going to device manager -> properties -> update driver! I wonder why reinstalling driver didn't solve.