# Device Chooser not showing the device in Eclipse (MacBook Pro)

Tags: android, eclipse, device, adb

I am working on Mac system, in my Eclipse when I right click on project and run it, it used to  run on the device but now suddenly its not showing the device in the Android Device Chooser

I have checked in USB debugging enabled on phone it enabled, I am using Nexus One.

I have also checked with few links :

[Why is Eclipse's Android Device Chooser not showing my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429959/why-is-eclipses-android-device-chooser-not-showing-my-android-device)

[Android Device Chooser -- device not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256884/android-device-chooser-device-not-showing-up)

But I am unable to solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried "adb devices" at the terminal to get a list of all connected devices? If your device is not shown please try to restart the adb server with "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server".

Comment: You should consider posting the solution you found as an answer

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Moved here as a community wiki answer, even though it is mainly a web link. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Thanks to this link here;
>
> http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=649663
>
> ok i solved it by myself i tried to kill the adb driver and started again and also my Nexus one is 2.3.3 which is api level 10 but my app was api level 11.

The link contains instructions on setting up and running adb on a Mac.