# Can't open APK file on smartphone

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I've made an application in eclipse using android project. Now I installed that APK-file on my smartphone.

When I hit install, it just installs, it's  fine. But then I get the option **"Cancel"**, or **"open"**. But I can't click on "Open".

Just nothing happens every time I try to open it. It's not with my other apps.

I can find it at "downloads", but I just can't open it. I can update and install it again countless times. Unknown sources in my settings is on.

Does anyone know this issue, and/or how to fix it?

Help would be appreciated.

Manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rodekruis"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BezoekActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.rodekruis.BezoekActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AfspraakActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_afspraak" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MeningActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mening" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RouteActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_route" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SpecialistenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_specialisten" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BWCActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bwc" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AgendaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_agenda" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".InfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_informatie" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VriendActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_vriend" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FoldersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_folders" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NieuwsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nieuws">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a launchable `Activity` in your app.

Comment: Do you have your phone one developer mode activated? You might want to see your ADB logs.

Comment: Share your manifest file.

Comment: @MikeM. I think you are right.

Comment: @Talha Mir I added my manifest

Comment: `MAIN` has to be all uppercase in `MainActivity`'s `<action>` - `android.intent.action.MAIN`.

Comment: Do I have to copy the APK File again to my mobile phone to update this little difference or can I just update it again on my phone straight away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you been able to launch it through ADB directly in Android Studio ?

You might want to do it this way during your implementation, it is much faster to build and test.

Just enable the developer mode in the settings and the "usb debugging" in the new menu that appeared (also in settings). You can now connect your phone to your computer and enjoy the simplicity of creating apps on Android.

Comment: For some reason, I tried that, but Eclipse can't seem to find my phone. It just doesn't appear.

Comment: I would personally recommend using Android Studio to develop Android applications, it integrates better functionalities.
In case you absolutely want to use Eclipse, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10612622/6329407) for your device detection.

Answer (score 0):

Register your launchable `Activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` like this-

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--______________Activities______________-->

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"  //launchable activity 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I think I have that. I added my manifest code, so you can see if i did something wrong there.